# "MS DTC has cancelled the distributed transaction" error in SQLCLR stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr, msdtc

I need to move some code from the old project to the new. Old project use DLL with stored procedures (32-bit version), but I need this DLL at 64-bit SQL Server, so I need to rewrite these procedures.

I am writing dll with stored procedures for SQL Server 2008. In Management Studio I load assembly, then create procedure by using:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
AS EXTERNAL NAME
```

Old DLL procedures just uses new connection to remote SQL Server to run stored procedure on it and return results.

So inside my procedure I create a `SqlConnection` to the remote server and run stored procedure on the remote server:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(String.Format("User ID={0};Password={1};Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog={2};Data Source={3}", Login, Password, DBName, ServerName)))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Exec ProcName", connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    SqlContext.Pipe.Send(reader);
}
```

If I run this procedure in SSMS, it works. But in the old project it raises error:

> The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction.

MSDTC service runs, and I set all security parameters. How to fix that? Maybe there are other ways to run remote stored procedures (linked server), but I need to save old project functionality.

Comment: DTC is involved in *transactions* Post the code that *starts* the transaction. Your stored procedure does something really evil - it opens a *new  connection* server which means that any existing transactions started by your code will have to escalate to distributed transactions using DTC. Why didn't you just create a linked server and call the remote procedure directly? In order to run that code you also had to relax SQLCLR security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that are not quite right going on here:

1. Why are you rewriting anything? If you have the code, worst case is just recompiling for the new architecture.
2. Why are you doing anything in the first place? The code should be compiled against "Any CPU" (under "Platform target" in the "SQLCLR Build" tab of "Project Properties") and not specifically for either 32 bit or 64 bit. And if it was already compiled under "Any CPU", then there is nothing to do. Have you tested on the new system before starting any recompiling and/or rewriting?
3. Don't use `String.Format` to create the Connection String. Instead, use [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx):

   ```cs
   SqlConnectionStringBuilder _ConnectionStringBuilder =
                                    new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

   _ConnectionStringBuilder.DataSource = ServerName;
   _ConnectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = DBName;
   _ConnectionStringBuilder.UserID = Login;
   _ConnectionStringBuilder.Password = Password;
   ```
4. Unless you absolutely have no choice and must use this option, do not specify `Persist Security Info=True;`
5. Instead of using `new SqlCommand()`, create the `SqlCommand` using:

   ```cs
   using(SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
   {
     command.CommandText = "Exec ProcName";
   }
   ```
6. Be sure to also specify `command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` so that it does an actual RPC call instead of an ad hoc query. This will require that you remove the text of "EXEC" from the current `CommandText` of "EXEC ProcName"; you can only specify `[[DatabaseName.]SchemaName.]ProcName`.
7. A `SqlDataReader` is a disposable object, just like `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`, so the `SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()` should be wrapped in a `using()` construct.

Once the items noted above have been corrected, you should be able to fix the error by simply setting the following property of the SqlConnectionStringBuilder: `_ConnectionStringBuilder.Enlist = false`.

For more detailed information and examples related to working with SQLCLR, please see the series that I am writing on this topic on SQL Server Central: [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/) (free registration is required to read content on that site).

Comment: 1. I only have code of old DLL, not entire project. And this code is on Pascal. Compiling under XE6 (to 64bit) resulted in problems with types and my team decided to write new library instead of refactoring old code. 3-7 Agree with you, thank you! I just have to remove `Exec` from the command text if I use `StoredProcedure` type.

Comment: @cerberus Yes, sorry about not mentioning to remove the `EXEC` as it can only be `[[DatabaseName.]SchemaName.]ProcName`. I forgot that was in there as I was trying to not forget the other details ;-). I will update my answer to include that bit. But, how is it that the old code is done in Pascal? Do you mean Delphi XE6? Does XE6 compile to .NET MSIL? According to https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/faq it doesn't. Or am I missing something?

Comment: old code is Delphi 7 project, it uses ODS API. so it has nothing with .net. we tried XE6 to build to 64bit platform, but there were a lot of errors with types. so we decided to write on c#

Comment: @cerberus Then maybe I am misunderstanding the old project entirely. Was the old project done as SQLCLR? I would guess not at this point since that would need to be .NET. I originally thought you were updating a SQLCLR project and not porting to SQLCLR.

Comment: i have delphi-application and delphi dll (32 bit), which uses ODS API. now i need to port this dll functions to c# dll and because ODS is old, i use sqlclr